# How can we know which post did the client request?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

User used my programm. My Program this is wpf browser.

I need to know what is going on a POST request.

For example a person enters the site through my program, select your search click "Search". webbrowser passes the request to post. Here is my request and need.

Comment: Does this mean you want to know where a `POST` to your site is coming from?

Comment: no. I do auto authorizer. and now need a function that will simply take a POST request. that would later change it.

Answer (score 0):

How about use FIDLER ?
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/